# Uri is not absolute

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying to unmarshall the following xml file with the method `Jaxb.unmarshall(String,Class)`. I always get the error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute:`

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<spieltag xmlns="http://arnezelasko.de/spieltag">
<game>
    <spieltag>28</spieltag>
    <nummer>1</nummer>
    <beginn>2010-03-26 20:30:00</beginn>
    <mannschaft_heim><![CDATA[VfL Bochum]]></mannschaft_heim>
    <mannschaft_gast><![CDATA[Eintracht Frankfurt]]></mannschaft_gast>
    <tore_heim_halbzeit>1</tore_heim_halbzeit>
    <tore_gast_halbzeit>1</tore_gast_halbzeit>
    <tore_heim_ergebnis>1</tore_heim_ergebnis>
    <tore_gast_ergebnis>2</tore_gast_ergebnis>
</game>
<game>
    <spieltag>28</spieltag>
    <nummer>2</nummer>
    <beginn>2010-03-27 15:30:00</beginn>
    <mannschaft_heim><![CDATA[Bayern München]]></mannschaft_heim>
    <mannschaft_gast><![CDATA[VfB Stuttgart]]></mannschaft_gast>
    <tore_heim_halbzeit></tore_heim_halbzeit>
    <tore_gast_halbzeit></tore_gast_halbzeit>
    <tore_heim_ergebnis></tore_heim_ergebnis>
    <tore_gast_ergebnis></tore_gast_ergebnis>
</game>
```

Comment: Post the complete code u r using for unmarshallinjg

Comment: Could you give us the XMLSchema ? Have you generated java files from an xmlschema using xjc ?

Comment: i see no `unmarshall(String,Class)` method on jaxb Unmarshaller?

Comment: Hi. Yes i created the files with xjc. the schema i have created with trang from the sample xml.File

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [working Java unmarshalling example](https://bitbucket.org/jrx/jrxpublic/downloads/12288390-uri-is-not-absolute.zip) from your xml example.

You have a root element called spieltag and an inner element that also called spieltag. That may cause problems if you have not well defined this in your XMLSchema. In the example, I've used `spieltag2` for the inner `spieltag` element.

Also, don't forget to compile package-info.java with the proper `@XmlSchema` :

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12296535/3673), You can use the `@XmlSchema` annotation on a `package-info` class to control the namespace qualification.  If you have already written a package-info class make sure it is being compiled (some versions of ant had problems with package-info classes).

**package-info**

```
@XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "http://arnezelasko.de/spieltag", 
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package de.arnezelasko.spieltag;
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html