# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:

Tags: java, jaxb

I am getting the following error when trying to convert xml response to java objects using jaxb

```
       javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://SOMETHING/doc/2006-03-01/", local:"Name"). Expected elements are <{}Name>,<{}IsTruncated>,<{}MaxKeys>,<{}Contents>,<{}Prefix>,<{}Marker>
```

Here is my XML :

```
       <ListBucketResult xmlns="http://something/doc/2006-03-01/">
           <Name>test2</Name>
            <Prefix/>
            <Marker/>
            <MaxKeys>3</MaxKeys>
            <IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated>
            <Contents>
                  <Key>metadata.xml</Key>
                  <LastModified>2012-09-04T08:29:36.000Z</LastModified>
                    <ETag>6b836fd43c402681506926b2248ec418</ETag>
                    <Size>3258</Size>
                   <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
             </Contents>
          </ListBucketResult>
```

And my java object classes are something like this

```
            @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "name",
        "prefix",
        "marker",
        "maxKeys",
        "isTruncated",
        "contents"
    })
    @XmlRootElement(name = "ListBucketResult")
    public class ListBucketResult {

@XmlElement(name = "Name", required = true)
protected String name;
@XmlElement(name = "Prefix", required = true)
protected String prefix;
@XmlElement(name = "Marker", required = true)
protected String marker;
@XmlElement(name = "MaxKeys")
protected int maxKeys;
@XmlElement(name = "IsTruncated")
protected boolean isTruncated;
@XmlElement(name = "Contents", required = true)
protected ListBucketResult.Contents contents;







         @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
         @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
                "key",
                "lastModified",
                   "eTag",
                   "size",
                 "storageClass"
           })
          public static class Contents {

    @XmlElement(name = "Key", required = true)
    protected String key;
    @XmlElement(name = "LastModified", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar lastModified;
    @XmlElement(name = "ETag", required = true)
    protected String eTag;
    @XmlElement(name = "Size")
    protected int size;
    @XmlElement(name = "StorageClass", required = true)
    protected String storageClass;
```

and finally my unmarshalling code is :

```
                          JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ListBucketResult.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new javax.xml.bind.helpers.DefaultValidationEventHandler());
               JAXBElement element = (JAXBElement) unmarshaller.unmarshal (inputStream);
            ListBucketResult customer = (ListBucketResult) element.getValue();
```

Could someone please let me know what am i doing incorrect ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XML document contains elements which are part of the 'http://something/doc/2006-03-01/' namespace, but the annotated java class is not associated with that namespace.  Try changing the @XmlType annotation to:

```
@XmlType(name = "", namespace="http://something/doc/2006-03-01/", propOrder = { ...
```

Comment: Hi , Changing this didnt help.

       @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
  @XmlType(name = "", namespace="http://something/doc/2006-03-01/", propOrder = {
      "name",
      "prefix",
      "marker",
      "maxKeys",
      "isTruncated",
      "contents"
  })

Comment: Regardless of mechanism, the problem is a namespacing issue.  The exception method indicates that an element with a fully-qualified name of {http://SOMETHING/doc/2006-03-01/}Name was provided (which is correct based on the xml provided) but that an element of {}Name (among others) is expected.  The latter is an element in the default  namespace.  Is the exception *exactly* the same now or has it changed slightly?

Comment: Hi
Thanks for all the comments. It is fixed just by removing 

             @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
                   "name",
                    "prefix",
                    "marker",
                   "maxKeys",
                   "isTruncated",
                   "contents"
                 })

Comment: Adding the namespace param to @XmlType annotation worked great for me!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `@XmlSchema` annotation on a `package-info` class to control the namespace qualification.  If you have already written a package-info class make sure it is being compiled (some versions of ant had problems with package-info classes).

**package-info**

```
@XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "http://something/doc/2006-03-01/", 
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar error **org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException** and **javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException** : with linked exception: [**javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"sometext", local:"elementA"). Expected elements are** .

This is when integrating **RESTEasy** and **Spring** with my DTO's generated using **JAXB**. I was using **Jackson** for conversion.

To solve it I introduced the Jackson library in the Maven dependency and it solved my problem. The jackson dependency that is specific to this was

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

There were other Jackson jars as well which I needed, so my POM Essentially looked as below.

```
   //The jackson-core-asl jar contains streaming JSON parser and generator interfaces and implementations
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
//Ability to use JAXB annotations containing classes needed to add XML compatibility support.
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
    //Mapper jar contains functionality for data binding: 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.9</version>
   </dependency> //This dependency makes a JAX-RS implementation like Jersey,RESTEasy use Jackson for binding of JSON to-from Java objects
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
```