# org.jooq.codegen.GeneratorException: Error while reading XML configuration

Tags: maven-3, jooq, java-10

I'm trying to move from Java 8 to Java 10 and face the following issue with JOOQ codegen Maven plug-in.

My environment:

1. java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
2. Apache Maven 3.3.9

pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                ...
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>${mysql-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.11</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.11</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
                    <version>3.11.5</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
                    <version>3.11.5</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <configurationFile>target/my_conf.xml</configurationFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

my_conf.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.11.0.xsd">

    <jdbc>
        <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
        <url>jdbc:mysql://${host}/${db_name}</url>
        <user>${user_username}</user>
        <password>${pwds}</password>
    </jdbc>

    <generator>
        <database>
            <name>org.jooq.meta.mysql.MySQLDatabase</name>
            <inputSchema>${db.sf_write_junit_db_name}</inputSchema>
    ...

    </generator>
</configuration>
```

The following Exceptions I see after execution:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.11.5:generate (jooq-generator-sf_read) on project sf-write-model: Execution jooq-generator-sf_read of goal org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.11.5:generate failed: org.jooq.codegen.GeneratorException: Error while reading XML configuration: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.11.0.xsd", local:"configuration"). Expected elements are <{}configuration> -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.11.5:generate (jooq-generator-sf_read) on project sf-write-model: Execution jooq-generator-sf_read of goal org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.11.5:generate failed: org.jooq.codegen.GeneratorException: Error while reading XML configuration
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
...
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution jooq-generator-sf_read of goal org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.11.5:generate failed: org.jooq.codegen.GeneratorException: Error while reading XML configuration
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jooq.codegen.GeneratorException: Error while reading XML configuration
        at org.jooq.codegen.maven.Plugin.execute(Plugin.java:144)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: org.jooq.codegen.GeneratorException: Error while reading XML configuration
        at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.load(GenerationTool.java:925)
        at org.jooq.codegen.maven.Plugin.execute(Plugin.java:139)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.11.0.xsd", local:"configuration"). Expected elements are <{}configuration>
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:740)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:262)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:257)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:124)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1148)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:573)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:555)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.startElement(ValidatingUnmarshaller.java:102)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:168)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3058)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:821)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:532)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:635)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:258)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:229)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:170)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:219)
        at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.load(GenerationTool.java:922)
```

But it works fine when I put content from **my_conf.xml** inside  element instead of using:

```
<configurationFile>target/my_conf.xml</configurationFile>
```

These two options give the same exception:

```
<!-- Option 1 -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.0.1</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <!-- Option 2 -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.0</version>
                    </dependency>
```

Any ideas why does it work this way and how to use a separate external file for JOOQ configuration?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you have a mismatch between the JAXB API and implementation versions in your dependencies. Can you try removing the API dependency, for example?

Comment: I have tried two options:
1. com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core 2.3.0 and jaxb-impl 2.3.0
2. org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime 2.3.01
the same exception Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.11.0.xsd", local:"configuration"). Expected elements are <{}configuration>

Comment: My issue is very similar to what I see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52157040/jaxb-package-info-ignored-when-using-java-10

Comment: @Lukas Eder - when I changed org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Configuration class and added annotation @XmlRootElement(name = "configuration", namespace = "http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.11.0.xsd") - so I got the following: Unmarshal warning        : unexpected element (uri:"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.11.0.xsd", local:"jdbc"). Expected elements are <{}logging>,<{}generator>,<{}jdbc>

Comment: My investigation shows that the problem is in Maven 3.5 and Java 10 during class loading the annotation javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema values is missing from JOOQ package-info.class (generated from XSD). In Java 8 it works fine and package annotation has value of "namespace" -> "http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.10.0.xsd". So I'm not sure is this issue in Maven 3.5 or Java 10.

Answer (score 0):

@Lukas Eder

This code works for me with Maven 3.6.0, Jdk 9.0.4,  jOOQ version 3.10.2, jaxb-api 2.3.1, org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime 2.3.1:

```
package org.jooq.util;

public class GenerationTool {

    public static Configuration load(InputStream in) throws IOException {
            ...

            JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(Configuration.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = ctx.createUnmarshaller();
            unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
            unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new ValidationEventHandler() {
                @Override
                public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
                    log.warn("Unmarshal warning", event.getMessage());
                    return true;
                }
            });

            final SAXParserFactory sax = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            sax.setNamespaceAware(false);
            final XMLReader reader = sax.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
            final Source er = new SAXSource(reader, new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
            return (Configuration) unmarshaller.unmarshal(er);
}
}
```